# SVG export with MiKTex using IguanaTex / Tex2img

Tags: svg, miktex

I'm trying to transfer some formulas from a ".tex" document into a PPT-presentation. Using the IguanaTex AddIn, I'm able to insert my Latex Code into the presentation, which is then compiled and by default converted to a ".png" graphic. Works fine.

But I would like to have the output vectorized with TeX2img as to make the presentation look better, but the conversion either fails (MiKTex doesn't recognize the documentclass) or size and location of the output change, distorting it.

What could be the problem? (or: How do I reset the TeX2img settings as to start looking for it myself?)